# How to have a new html file created when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a django project trying to create a forum.

Now when a user creates a new thread, I need to have a new html file created with a unique url.

For example if a user creates a thread with the title "What's the best programming language?" a new html file with some standard template has to be created (and a function in views.py as well as a path in urls.py) and the url should be something like "mysitetitle.com/what's-the-best-programming-language?".

That would be relevant code of my project.

views.py

```
def create_thread(request):
    form = CreateForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            f.benutzername = request.user
            f.save()
            messages.success(request, "Thread has been created.")
```

create_thread.html

```
{% extends "forum/index.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Create Thread {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container-create">
    <h2 class="heading-create">Diskussion erstellen</h2>
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="thread-info">{{ message }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if not user.username %}
        <div class="guest-login">As <span class="guest">Guest</span> or <a class="login-link" href="../login">Login</a></div>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label class="label-create-topic" for="create-topic">Topic</label>
        {{form.topic}}
        <label class="label-create-title" for="create-title">Title</label>
        {{form.title}}
        <label class="label-create-content" for="create-content">Content</label>
        {{form.content}}
        <button class="submit-create" id="submit-create" type="submit" value="Create">Create</button>
    </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can just create a Django view to render your forum page's HTML template. The same template can be used to render the HTML of all your forums so there's no need to create multiple HTML files

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Could you maybe elaborate your thought? I must say that I'm a beginner, so yeah...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create new HTML files for every single forum because the Django HTML templates are meant to be reusable, so you can use a single template for all your forums.

So what you need is a way for the relevant data for each forum (such as titles, posts etc) to be passed to the template, which will then be rendered by a Django view.

First, you will need a database Model for your forums, so that you are able to save each forum's data in your database. Then, you will use a combination of Django's path variables in the URL and the Django view function to get the relevant data and pass it to your template.

Here is an example for you:

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class ForumModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In models.py I have defined a sample database model for your forum. You will need to customize this to your own needs.

views.py

```
from django.views import View
from .models import ForumModel

class ForumView(View):
    def get(self, request, forum_title):
        forum = ForumModel.objects.get(title=forum_title)
        # Render your template here by passing your data to the template
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import ForumView

urlpatterns = [
    # Use path parameter forum_title to pass data from url to django view
    path("forums/<str:forum_title>", ForumView.as_view())
]
```

Comment: As a side note it would be useful to follow Django's tutorial, as it covers these concepts in greater detail